# What would be best practice If I am trying to constantly check if a directory exists? JAVA

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

I have a Java application that creates multiple threads. There is 1 producer thread which reads from a 10gb file, parses that information, creates objects from it and puts them into multiple blocking queues (5 queues).

The rest of the 5 consumer threads read from a blockingqueue (each consumer thread has its own blockingqueue). The consumer threads then each write to an individual file, so 5 files in total get created. It takes around 30min to create all files.

**The problem:**
The threads are writing to an external mount directory in a linux box. We've experience problems where other linux mounts have gone down and applications crash so I want to prevent that in this application.

**What I would like to do is keep checking if the mount (directory) exists before writing to it. Im assuming if the directory goes down it will throw a FileNotFoundException. If that is the case I want it to keep checking if the directory is there for about 10-20min before completely crashing. Because I dont want to have to read the 10gb file again I want the consumer threads to be able to pick up from where they last left off.**

**What Im not sure would be best practice is:**

Is it best to check if the directory exists in the main class before creating the threads? Or check in each consumer thread?

If I keep checking if the directory exists in each consumer thread it seems like repeatable code. I can check in the main class but it takes 30min to create these files. What if in those 30min the mount goes down then if Im only checking in the main class whether the directory exists the application will crash. Or if Im already writing to a directory is it impossible for an external directory to go down? Does it get locked?

thank you

Comment: your consumer thread is a writer, how do you expect it will pick up where last left off when the destination is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have something similar in our application, but in our case we are running a web app and if our mounted file system goes down we just throw an exception, but we want to do something more elegant, like you do...

I would recommend using a combination of the following patterns:  [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), [CircuitBreaker](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html), which I believe CircuitBreaker is a more specific version of the State pattern, and [Observer/Observable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

These would work in the following way...

Create something that represents your file system.  Maybe a class called MountedFileSystem.  Make all your write calls to this particular class.

This class will catch all FileNotFoundException and one occurs, the CircutBreaker gets triggered.  This change will be like the State pattern.  One state is when things are working 'fine', the other state is when things aren't working 'fine', meaning that the mount has gone away.

Then, in the background, I would have a task that starts on a thread and checks the actual underlying file system to see if it is back.  When the file system is back, change the state in the MountedFileSystem, and fire an Event (Observer/Observable) to try writing the files again to disk.

And as yuan quigfei stated, I am fairly certain you're going to have to rewrite those files.  I just don't see being able to restart writing to them, but perhaps someone else has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. write a method to detect folder exist or not.
2. call this method before actual writing.
3. create 5 thread based on 2. Once detect file is not existed, you seems have no choice but rewrite. Of course, you don't need re-read if all your content are in memory already(Big memory).